# Directive taking same instance's scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to create a d3.js directive, and it's currently working fine.
But, when i'm resizing the window, my first directive takes the second directive values. How can I seperate the two in order to resize them correctly?

(they already have an isolate scope btw).

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/1GdEeug8k8Op2PWXFTqo

Here is the part where my console return the same object :

```
              $window.onresize = function() {
                console.log(scope);
          };
```

And here is what i see in my console.

[image]

Comment: When I am resizing the window each graph still has its own and different data, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Well, first they load with their own and correct data, but if i want to resize them in the "$window.onresize = function() {}" i can't get access to the first directive values and I don't know why

Comment: You have no problem, you just need to reach the first directive's scope using the parent scope of the second directive. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have everything configured fine, when you resize each graph still has its own data.

The only thing you didn't take into account that you log only the isolated scope of the second directive.

Update the log to:

```
console.log(scope.$parent.data);
console.log(scope.$parent.data2);
```

And you will see you can reach each isolated scope data using the parent.

Comment: Thx it works just fine!
But I still don't know why my directives share the same scope when the "resize" event occur, I thought isolated scope give a different scope for each directives

Comment: They have different scopes, my guess is that only the resize of the second directive is being handled so if you got to scope you see the second directive's scope.

Comment: yeah after some times I just discovered that if you have multiple "onresize" event, only the last one will be fired. So i used d3 to make multiple one :               **d3.select(window).on('resize.choosename' , function (){});**
and now i don't have to use scope.$parent, which is nice since I prefer having directives attributes. Anyway, thx for the help